# Best way to handle large input data from Excel in Javascript / Google Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, visualization, data-visualization

I'm learning to use Google Charts API in order to play around with data from [UNODOC statistics](https://data.unodc.org/). 
I found [this](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiwhM7MtMLIAhUFthQKHbBWC48&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.unodc.org%2Fdocuments%2Fgsh%2Fdata%2FGSH2013_Homicide_count_and_rate.xlsx&usg=AFQjCNH8FLLUiD62C2Y1EaGD8wi8P_fUhg) excel file providing information about homicide count and rates from countries in the world in the years 2000-2013.

I created an area line chart with Google Charts displaying homicide count and rate in USA.
Here is the complete [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/8lU9fjRHLQjP5xI2PCBf?p=preview). As you can see I am displaying data only from the USA, and I am hardcoding the data into the `var data`/`var data1` and `options`/`options1` variables directly into the javascript file.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Rate'],
        ['2000' , 5.5],  
        ['2001' , 6.6],
        ['2002' , 5.6],
        ['2003' , 5.6],
        ['2004' , 5.5],
        ['2005' , 5.6],
        ['2006' , 5.8],
        ['2007' , 5.6],
        ['2008' , 5.4],
        ['2009' , 5.0],
        ['2010' , 4.7],
        ['2011' , 4.7],
        ['2012' , 4.7],
        ['2013' , 3.8],
    ]);

var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Homocide count'],
            ['2000' , 15586],
            ['2001' , 19033],
            ['2002' , 16229],
            ['2003' , 16528],
            ['2004' , 16148],
            ['2005' , 16740],
            ['2006' , 17309],
            ['2007' , 17128],
            ['2008' , 16465],
            ['2009' , 15399],
            ['2010' , 14722],
            ['2011' , 14661],
            ['2012' , 14827],
            ['2013' , 12253],
      ]);
```

First of all, I don't think this is nice, especially if I want to input data from all the countries comprehended in the Excel file.

What would the best way to load all of the data be, without copy-pasting all the data by hand from the `.xls` file into the javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you convert xls to csv first? If so, I'd lean towards using the d3.csv() function.

```
d3.csv('file.csv', function(murderData){
    chart here using murderData
})
```

Load your chart/map as a callback.
 M Bostock has [the medicine](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV)

EG CSV -

```
Year,Make,Model,Length
1997,Ford,E350,2.34
2000,Mercury,Cougar,2.38
```

Gets returned

```
[
  {"Year": "1997", "Make": "Ford", "Model": "E350", "Length": "2.34"},
  {"Year": "2000", "Make": "Mercury", "Model": "Cougar", "Length": "2.38"}
]
```

Comment: I converted to csv file, but how to retrieve a specific row?

Comment: The function returns an array of objects, similar to the array of arrays that you had originally. Therefore, to get the first row (excluding labels), select `data[1]`. To get the length of the last row in the csv example, select `data[2].Length`.

Comment: And, I meant the Length element, not the object length, just to be really clear.